# Export a class with std::string

Tags: c++, stl, dllexport

I know this subject has been covered and re-talked, but I still get stuck every time I need to do something like that, and the internet is full of different answers.
so I decided to simply ask how to deal with such situation once and for all.

Lets say I have the following class:

```
class PETS_EXPORT_API dog
{
public:
  dog(std::string name):_name(name){}
  ~dog(){}

private:
  std::string _name;
};
```

Obviously this code would generate a warning because I'm trying to export std::string. How do I solve such issue ?

thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to export private members?

Comment: Remember to use `const std::string&` as parameters instead of `std::string`, to avoid unnecessary copying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative to Joe McGrath's answer:

If you really want your clients to have access to `Dog` public & protected interface, and does *not* make sense to have an abstract interface,

- You could use the *pImpl idiom*, to hide the private interface.
- Additionally you could export the string in the form of chars

Hide your original *dog*:

```
class Dog_Impl // your original class
{

public:
  Dog_Impl(std::string name):_name(name){}
  ~Dog_Impl(){}

  string::get_name();
private:
  std::string _name;

};
```

Put this into your API:

```
class Dog_Impl; // fwd declaration

class PETS_EXPORT_API Dog {
  public:
    Dog(const char *name);
    ~Dog();
    const char *get_name();

  private:
    Dog_Impl *pImpl;
};
```

The implementation should simply pass all public & protected interface to the *pImpl*:

```
Dog::Dog(const char *name) 
{
  pImpl = new Dog_Impl(name);
}

Dog::~Dog()
{ 
  delete pImpl;
}

const char *Dog::get_name()
{
  return pImpl->get_name().c_str(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to export the private members. Only the public interface. Make an abstract base class and export it.

```
struct DogInterface
{
    virtual string IAmADog(void) = 0; // your public interface goes here
};

// Factory function that creates dogs
extern "C" PETS_EXPORT_API DogInterface* APIENTRY GetDog();
```

If you just want to export the string for access

```
__declspec(dllexport) const char* MyExportedString()
{
   return myString.c_str()
}
```

Comment: Hey @Joe, Thanks for you answer.
What do you think about interface called "class dog" and implementation called "class dog_impl" and a factory class called "class dog_factory" that returns a new dog?

Comment: Names are all semantics, what's important is consistency and agreement among everyone working on the project. Beyond that it sounds good :)